# reload tab and reload frame is not working same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams-js

I have create react application in microsoft teams using teamsjs library in my application reload frame is working fine but refresh teams is not working fine can you please share example or any help regarding this issue

I am using tab application in react js with teams application try to make different pages using react navigation but when refresh tab It always navigate to first page but I want to show current page.

I have create react application in microsoft teams using teamsjs library in my application reload frame is working fine but refresh teams is not working fine can you please share example or any help regarding this issue

Comment: Perhaps you've *done something wrong™* in your code, or *done something wrong™* in your code, or *done something wrong™* in your code?